# Having Windows XP search a stack of folders for an appropriate driver like Win7 does

Tags: windows-xp, drivers, device-manager

I downloaded a huge archive of drivers for use on a USB stick if I'm ever troubleshooting a user in the land of no internet. With Windows 7, I point Device Manager at the root folder of the archive, and it searches through it for the right driver. With XP, it doesn't let you do that.

Any ideas? The folders are not clearly marked with vendor names so I can't manually find them in the archive.

Answer (score 1):

The solution for problem is to burn your huge collection of drivers on DVD and than you have to use Device Manager to "search for driver automatically" (checked option "search from CD"), and Windows XP will search automatically entire DVD and find the appropriate driver. In XP, this driver search function work only for CD/DVD search, not for hard disk or USB stick search like Windows 7 do.

Comment: Also you could use something like [MagicISO](http://www.magiciso.com/) to create ISO files and load them into a virtual CD drive like [Virtual Clone Drive](http://www.slysoft.com/en/virtual-clonedrive.html). Then you should get the same action without messing with any hardware.

Comment: That is most elegant, but a little complicated solution. What is easier, to burn files on CD/DVD or to search software for ISO creating and virtual CD making and instaling and seting all that things? However, it can be helpful for game players who already have these programs installed.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to be troubleshooting a system anyway and already have a usb stick.....
Try portableapps.com. It is a portable launcher with lots of handy portable tools including cd/dvd emulation. It can also be set to autorun any of the portable apps at startup.
In your situation, simply set it to autorun 'WinCDEmu' and set that app to autoload your drivers ISO.